# Database access in C

Tags: c, database

I am developing an application completely written in **C**. I have to save data permanently somewhere. I tried file storage but I feel its really a primitive manner to do the job and I don't want to save my sensitive data in a simple text file. How can i save my data and access it back in an easy manner? I come from JavaScript background and would prefer something like jsons. I will be happy with something like postgreSQL also. Give me some suggestions. I am using `gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3`.

Comment: [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 4):

[sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) seems to meet your requirements.

> SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. Unlike most other SQL
>   databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process. SQLite
>   reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files. A complete SQL
>   database with multiple tables, indices, triggers, and views, is
>   contained in a single disk file. The database file format is
>   cross-platform - you can freely copy a database between 32-bit and
>   64-bit systems or between big-endian and little-endian architectures.
>   These features make SQLite a popular choice as an Application File
>   Format. Think of SQLite not as a replacement for Oracle but as a
>   replacement for fopen()

Check out the [quickstart](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quickstart link

Answer (score 2):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq.html

> libpq is the C application programmer's interface to PostgreSQL. libpq is a set of library functions that allow client programs to pass queries to the PostgreSQL backend server and to receive the results of these queries.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. My application requires to save only a small amount of data and it needs something really light. I think i will go for sqlite this time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). I think it is a great way of storing local data.

There are C library bindings, and its API is quite simple.

Its main advantage is that all you need is the library. You don't need a complex database server setup (as you would with PostgreSQL). Also, its footprint is quite small (it's also used a lot in mobile development world {iOS, android, others}).

Its drawback is that it doesn't handle concurrency that well. But if it is a local, simple, single-threaded application, then I guess it won't be a problem.

[MySQL embedded](http://www.mysql.com/oem/) or [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) are other options you might want to take a look at.

Comment: Best resources are on the link I already provided. Take a look at it. SQLite documentation is pretty decent.

Comment: App will have to handle multi threaded situations :( I am making a small chat server in c.

Comment: Then I would recommend serializing access to database file with only one thread handling all of it, or using a more robust product (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Firebird, BerkeleyDB).

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a lightweight database. This page describes the C language interface:

- http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.

Comment: Okey, seems like this is the right option.. Digging on it already

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a popular choice because it's light-weight and speedy. It also offers a [C/C++ interface](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html) (including a bunch of other languages).

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else has already mentioned SQLite, so I'll counter with dbm:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/dbm_open

It's not quite as fancy as SQLite (e.g, it's not a full SQL database), but it's often easier to work with from C, as it requires less setup.

Comment: I need the simplest option available.. Dont really care about the performance since application size is small.